# Google Analytics in R Token creation Process

Tags: r, token, google-analytics-api

So, I'm new to R and I'm still learning. 
I have a token to authenticate the google analytics connection to R.
Currently I'm just using `Load("./token")` in my script to load the token automatically and extract the data.

I want to know if I can include something in the script
to check if the token exists and if it doesn't exist I want to do the whole token creation process-

```
client.id<-"xyz"
client.secret<-"123"

token=Auth(client.id,client.secret)
save (token,file="./token")
```

and then run `Load("./token")`

And if the token already exists, skip the create token process and just directly run `Load("./token")`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use file.exists() function like this:

```
if(!file.exists("./Token")){
 client.id<-"xyz"
 client.secret<-"123"
 token=Auth(client.id,client.secret)
 save (token,file="./token.txt")
 load("./token")
} else {load("./token")
```